# Ruach Elohim and Ruach HaShem and a good or bad effect

Tags: shemos-sacred-names, samuel-shmuel-book-of

In the verse of 1 Samuel 18:10 is spoken of Ruach Elohim, while in 1 Samuel 19:9 in a same sort of context is spoken of Ruach HaShem, are these the same? Or is there a slight difference in use of Elohim or HaShem when refering to G'ds Ruach?

P.s. could someone explain me how having G'ds Ruach could sometimes have a good effect (as seen with Moshe for example) and sometimes a bad effect (as seen with Shaul)?

Comment: From commentaries in Artscroll English Tanach, HaShem reflect the attribute of mercy, while Elokim reflect the attribute of Judgement.

Comment: How do mercy and the fact that the Ruach in 1Samuel 19:9 is linked to rah (wrong/bad/evil) go together?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Mike! Thanks for sharing your question. Consider taking the following two minute [tour](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about the site. Hope to see you around.

Comment: there would have to be some difference because the end result of the prior (which "passed") use was Saul's saying words and the later one (which "was") did not bring about any words.

Comment: @Mike I am not relating them together. I meant generally

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/59536/2091

Answer (score 1):

As you stated in your comment, Samuel 1 19:9 describes an "evil spirit", quite different from the other spirit you referenced in your question.

Therefore it is 2 different "types" of "ruchot" you're referencing, i.e. one evil, one "normal".

As it says: I form the light, and create darkness; **I make peace, and create evil**; I am the LORD, that doeth all these things. (Isaiah 45:7)